# PL/SQL Oracle interaction

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql

I have a `for` loop that I iterate through.
I would like to save each `i.PROCESS` and `i.AGE_OF_DATA` in `COUNTS` table.
How do i accomplish this?

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 
    (
       SELECT PROCESS, max(protDate) as AGE_OF_DATA 
       FROM tablestats GROUP BY PROCESS
    )
LOOP
     INSERT INTO COUNTS(MODEL_NAME, CLASS_NAME, CLASS_INSTANCE_COUNT, COUNT_DATETIME,       PROCESS_NAME, AGE)
     VALUES( '$MODEL','${i}', 
             (SELECT COUNT(S) FROM PROCESS),
              (SELECT MAX(DATE_TIME) FROM TABLE3),
              i.PROCESS, i.AGE_OF_DATA
           );
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I get an error:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid
```

I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: BTW, seems like you're missing the `GROUP BY` clause from your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `FOR` loop here, just use the `INSERT-SELECT` construct:

```
INSERT INTO counts (process_name, age)
SELECT process, MAX(protDate) 
FROM   tablestats
```

Comment: The `INSERT-SELECT` construct supports inserting multiple rows. Can you elaborate on the problem you have with it?

Comment: anyone knows how to use for loops and pass to INSERT?

Answer (score 1):

As the query inside the `for` loop generator failed with syntax error, the variable I had no definition, and hence it is a cascading effect ending with `INVALID` usage.